# Can't convert Matrix to DataFrame JULIA

Tags: dataframe, matrix, julia

How can i convert a matrix to DataFrame in Julia?

I have an 10×2 Matrix{Any}, and when i try to convert it to a dataframe, using this:

```
df2 = convert(DataFrame,Xt2)
```

i get this error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Matrix{Any} to an object of type DataFrame
```

Answer (score 6):

Try instead

```
df2 = DataFrame(Xt2,:auto)
```

You cannot use `convert` for this; you can use the `DataFrame` constructor, but then as the documentation (simply type `? DataFrame` in the Julia REPL) will tell you, you need to either provide a vector of column names, or `:auto` to auto-generate column names.

Tangentially, I would also strongly recommend avoiding `Matrix{Any}` (or really anything involving `Any`) for any scenario where performance is at all important.